# Parsing HTML tags using Java

Tags: java, html, html-parsing

I am trying to create a HTML parser that checks the HTML tags and verifies that there is a closing tag that corresponds to every open tag.

What I have now works partially and I believe the logic is correct, but I am having issues getting the tokens correct. When I run the code I have, it takes lots of empty tokens, which when are compared to other non-empty ones, obviously produce an error.

I'm wondering how I can get it to read from my HTML file, but only put things into tokens that are between < and >. I also don't want any extra data, such as text between a h1 tags to be taken into account for tokens.

This is for a school assignment and I believe the professor wants us to do this without the use of a 3rd party program, like JTidy.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.io.*;


public class HTMLDriver
{
   public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException
   {
     // declare variables
     QueueReferenceBased queue = new QueueReferenceBased();

     // Create a scanner object 

     Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.println("What is your html file name?");
     String fileName = in.next();

     File userFile = new File(fileName);

     if (!userFile.exists())
     {
        System.out.println("File does not exist. This program will now exit.");
        System.exit(0);
     }

    Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(userFile); 
    while (inputFile.hasNext())
    {

        String str = inputFile.nextLine();
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(str,"<>");

       //Adds tokens to queue
       while(st.hasMoreTokens())
       {
       String token = st.nextToken();
       Tag t = new Tag(token);
       queue.enqueue(t);
      }
    }   
    //Creates Stack
    StackReferenceBased stack = new StackReferenceBased();

    //Loops through queue if not empty
    while(!queue.isEmpty())
    {
      Object obj = queue.dequeue();
      Tag t2 = (Tag)obj;

        if(t2.getOpen() == true)
        {
           stack.push(t2);
        }

        if(t2.getOpen() == false)
        {
           if(stack.isEmpty())
           {
              System.out.println("There is no match for the " + t2 + " tag");
           }else
           {
              Object obj2 = stack.pop();
              Tag t3 = (Tag)obj2;

              //Make tag class and check equality

              if(t2.getTag().equals(t3.getTag()))
              {
                 System.out.println(t2 + " matches " + t3);
              }else
              {
                 System.out.println("Found " + t2 + " to match " + t3 + " terminating program");
                 System.exit(0);
              }

           }
        }
    }    
  }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this. Html is notorious in this regard. Some tags have no openning/closing < > -- then there is all the malformed HTML just out there and browser quirkiness.

Unless your professor explicitly excludes you from using a 3rd party lib then this is insanity to attempt on a robust scale. On XML, this is manageable.

If you really, really must do this on your own, decent results can be had using regular expression

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<(.*)>") // will get your started. you can then do:

Matcher m = p.matcher();
m.group( ... ) // this will get you everything between parentheses in the regex
```

Comment: I can't disagree more. Browsers use a more sophisticated process of the same fashion to parse HTML, tokenising the input stream in sequence and building up a stack of tag tokens. The OP is learning the rudiments of that. Regex is a dead-end when it comes to parsing HTML.

Comment: I've never used regular expressions before, so I'm a little confused on how to do it properly. I tried searching a bit for tutorials, but I'm still confused.

When I use the code you posted, it gives me an error that states there is an error with the Matcher m = p.matcher(); and that it cannot be applied to given types. Am I supposed to be putting my string in there as a parameter?

I'm also confused on how m.group works. Is that where i put my string into? Sorry if I seem pretty clueless, it's my first time with regular expressions are they're kinda hard for me.

Comment: It's a dead-end to do this on your own. I make that clear. As stated, you can get "manageable" results using regex.

As for browsers, any web dev can tell you that each browsers is full of quirks and bugs. They can be both sophisticated and buggy. 

Litheon, I am happy to give some regex pointers -- message me out of band. My strongest suggestion to you is to verify this is what your instructor wants